# card in bootstrap MDBootstrap cant set width:0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

I hava a card, this card act as sideNav(because the sideNav of mdbootstrap is only in paid version), if I set `width:0` the content of the sideNav/card look like this [image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cGj3.png)

---

code:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpwzp601/

---

Thanks

Comment: so what do you want to do

Comment: I want if `width:0` the card is hidden

Comment: that's the wrong way to do that...If you want to hide why don't you use css ```display:none```

Comment: because under the sidenav there is a video, with `display:none` I cant click on the video where the sidenav was.

Comment: I think you need to do little practice with coding the things you are telling sounds like a noob...thats not the way to do things...dont take it offensive but you are using a wrong method...I think you are a learner

Comment: i sounds like a noob because my english is not very good, and its very hard to say correct what I need

Comment: well bro just practice...bcz practice makes a man perfect :) you are doing a simple thing in a Very complicated manner...so i said so...just practice and be a developer